# How can one pass values from a web page to a RDLC report running in local mode?

Tags: reporting-services

Local Mode Reporting Services has limitations compared to remote Report Server version but it is needed for many scenarios with hosted SMBs since SQL Server 2012 Web Edition is much more cost effective for small companies and it only permits local mode reports.

However, if I want to use dynamic values from the web page (such as parameter values) I cannot reference them from the RDLC and therefore cannot access them.  I can update the dataset that the Report returns by passing values to "ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters..." but these values aren't available in the report (they shape the data returned but are not in themselves available).

For example, if parameters included the date bounds of a query I could not get the "StartDate" parameter expressed as a heading via an expression.  Of course, I can get the Date of the first record returned and show that via an expression, but I might have queried from June 1 and the first item might be dated June 3.  My report would be better if I could label the query range "June 1" in my header. I could also nest the report in a web page and handle the labeling that way but then my PDF/Excel output would still be displeasing.

The only other thing that I can think of (that seems quite inelegant) is to add metadata tables to the project database to query for the express purpose of returning values to garnish the report.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know much about local reporting but... If you can't access the parameters via the normal parameters collection, could you add them as additional fields in the raw query for your dataset?

Comment: Report parameters and Query Parameters are distinct.  "You cannot use the Report Parameters dialog box to map report parameters to query parameters or use them in data source filters. In local processing mode, all data processing is handled independently of report processing." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms251750(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, I can pass report parameters in from the code behind to shape the report (the parameters are passed to the Dataset), but I can't otherwise access the RDLC.